# How can I make sure my Python3 web application is "thread safe?"

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, thread-safety

I'm working on a python3 web application and, before I start, I want to make sure my code is "thread safe."

I'm not using a web framework like django or flask, and am instead using http.server to return JSON results to the browser. I'm storing sessions in a MySQL database and doing some simple image manipulation (upload/resize/save).

How can I ensure my Python3 application is thread safe? Is this necessary, and are there specific guidelines to follow?

Comment: This question is a little bit broad right now. There are [language-agnostic guidelines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety#Implementation_approaches) to follow for thread safety, e.g. if you have state shared between threads, you need to serialize access to it using a mutex. But it's hard to give a Python-specific answer without a concrete example of what you're actually doing to be doing in your application.

Comment: @dano thanks for the feedback. let me re-word the question, because i'm trying to learn how to do this correctly for my application